# Java applet buttons are not displayed until i hover the mouse over them

Tags: java, swing

So My problem is that the applet lunches with nothing in it as soon as i hover the mouse 
on top of the buttons it displays them and works perfectly afterwards. I think there might be something wrong with paint but i am not sure. I tried several changes but noting seems to work. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

-- Rafael

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class poker extends JApplet implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {

    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    JList jList = new JList(listModel);
    JButton dealButton = new JButton("Deal");
    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    JButton finishButton = new JButton("finish");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel lPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JLabel balance = new JLabel();

    private String displayDeal = null;
    private String displayFinish = null;
    private poker.Card deck[];
    private int currentCard;
    private double money = 0;
    private poker.Card hand[];
    private boolean nothing;
    private boolean pair;
    private boolean twoPair;
    private boolean threeKind;
    private boolean fourKind;
    private boolean fullHouse;
    private boolean flush;
    private boolean straight;
    private boolean royalStraight;
    private boolean straightFlush;
    private boolean RoyalFlush;

    String faces[] = {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
        "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    String suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

    @Override
    public void init() {

        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        jList.addListSelectionListener(this);
        jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        hand = new poker.Card[5];
        deck = new poker.Card[52];
        currentCard = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            deck[i] = new poker.Card(faces[i % 13], suits[i / 13]);
        }

        listModel.setSize(5);

        dealButton.addActionListener(this);
        finishButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);
        finishButton.setEnabled(false);

        panel.add(dealButton);
        panel.add(finishButton);
        panel.add(quitButton);
        panel.add(label);

        jPanel.add(jList);

        add(balance, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(jPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    class Card {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return face + " of " + suit + "\n";
        }

        public String getFace() {
            return face;
        }

        public String getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }
        private String face;
        private String suit;

        public Card(String s, String s1) {
            face = s;
            suit = s1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

        int[] indices = jList.getSelectedIndices();
        if (indices.length > 4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You may only select four "
                    + "cards.");
            jList.clearSelection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        poker.Card card = null;

        if (event.getSource() == dealButton) {////////////////////////////

            finishButton.setEnabled(true);
            dealButton.setEnabled(false);
            label.setText(null);

            shuffle();//  reset deck

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                card = dealCard();
                hand[j] = card;
                listModel.setElementAt(hand[j], j);

            }
            if (money < -1000) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GAME OVER. You have no "
                        + "more money. ");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            //evaluate();
            label.setText(displayDeal);
            displayDeal = null;

        } else if (event.getSource() == finishButton) {///////////////////////

            dealButton.setEnabled(true);
            finishButton.setEnabled(false);
            int c = 5;    //to get new card from deck 

            int maxIndex = jList.getMaxSelectionIndex();

            for (int l = 0; l <= maxIndex; l++) {
                if (jList.isSelectedIndex(l)) {
                    listModel.removeElementAt(l);
                    listModel.add(l, deck[c]);
                    c++;
                }
            }
            jList.revalidate();
            jPanel.repaint();

            evaluate();
            giveMoney();

            label.setText(displayFinish);
            balance.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            balance.setText("Money: $" + money );


            jList.clearSelection();
            displayFinish = null;

        } else if (event.getSource() == quitButton) {///////////////////////

            label.setText(null);
            balance.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            balance.setText("You have won $" + money + " dollars.");

            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Are you sure you want to exit?", "User Confirmation",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                dealButton.setEnabled(false);
                finishButton.setEnabled(false);
                quitButton.setEnabled(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.validate();
    }
    // giveMoney() keeps track of the money.

    public void giveMoney() {

        if (nothing) {
            money += -20.00;
            nothing = false;
        }
        if (pair) {
            money += 50.00;
            pair = false;
        }
        if (twoPair) {
            money += 100.00;
            twoPair = false;
        }
        if (threeKind) {
            money += 150.00;
            threeKind = false;           
        }
        if (straight) {
            money += 200.00;
            straight = false;
        }
        if (royalStraight) {
            money += 200.00;
            royalStraight = false;
        }
        if (flush) {
            money += 250.00;
            flush = false;
        }
        if (fullHouse) {
            money += 300;
        }
        if (fourKind) {
            money += 400.00;
            fourKind = false;
        }
        if (straightFlush) {
            money += 500.00;
            straightFlush = false;
        }
        if (RoyalFlush) {
            money += 1000.00;
            RoyalFlush = false;
        }

        this.validate();
    }

    // populates deck array 
    public void shuffle() {

        currentCard = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            int j = (int) (Math.random() * 52D);
            poker.Card card = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = card;
        }
        this.validate();
    }

    public poker.Card dealCard() {

        if (++currentCard < deck.length) {
            return deck[currentCard];
        } else {
            dealButton.setEnabled(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void evaluate() {

        int i = 0;
        String setOf = null;

        nothing = false; pair = false; twoPair = false; threeKind = false;
        straight = false; royalStraight = false; flush = false;
        fullHouse = false; fourKind = false; straightFlush = false;
        RoyalFlush = false;

        if (hand[0].getSuit().equals(hand[1].getSuit())
                && hand[1].getSuit().equals(hand[2].getSuit())
                && hand[2].getSuit().equals(hand[3].getSuit())
                && hand[3].getSuit().equals(hand[4].getSuit())) {
            flush = true;
            displayDeal = "You have a flush";
            displayFinish = "Flush. Win $250.00 dollars.";

        }
        if (sort2(hand) && !royalStraight) {
            straight = true;
            displayDeal = "You have a straight";
            displayFinish = "Straight. Win $200.00 dollars.";
        }
        if (straight && flush) {
            straightFlush = true;
            straight = false;
            flush = false;
            displayDeal = "You have a straight Flush";
            displayFinish = "straight Flush. Win $500.00 dollars.";

        }
        if (straightFlush) {
            for (int j = 9; j < 13; j++) {
                if (hand[i].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 3].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 4].getFace().equals(faces[j])) {
                    straightFlush = false;
                    RoyalFlush = true;
                    displayDeal = "You have a royal Flush";
                    displayFinish = "Royal Flush. Win $1000.00 dollars.";
                }
            }
        }
        if (straight) {
            for (int j = 9; j < 13; j++) {
                if (hand[i].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 3].getFace().equals(faces[j])
                        && hand[i + 4].getFace().equals(faces[j])) {
                    straight = false;
                    royalStraight = true;
                    displayDeal = "You have a royal straight";
                    displayFinish = "royal Straight. Win $200.00 dollars.";
                }
            }
        }
        if (hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())) {
            fourKind = true;
            displayDeal = "You have a four of a kind";
            displayFinish = "Four of a kind. Win $400.00 dollars.";
        } else if (hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && !fullHouse) {
            twoPair = true;
            displayDeal = "You have two pairs. ";
            displayFinish = "Two Pairs. Win $100.00 dollars.";
        } else if (hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && !straightFlush) {
            fullHouse = true;
            displayDeal = "You have a full house.";
            displayFinish = "Full House. Win $300.00 dollars.";
        }
        if ((hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                || hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace())
                && hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())
                && hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())
                || hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace())
                && hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()))
                && !twoPair && !fullHouse && !fourKind) {
            threeKind = true;          
            displayDeal = "You have three of a kind of " + setOf + "s.";
            displayFinish = "three of a kind of " + setOf + "s. Win $150.00 dollars.";
        } else if ((hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 1].getFace())
                || hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 2].getFace())
                || hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace())
                || hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace())
                || hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 2].getFace())
                || hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace())
                || hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace())
                || hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace())
                || hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace())
                || hand[i + 3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()))
                && !twoPair && !threeKind && !fullHouse) {
            pair = true;
            displayDeal = "You have a pair of " + setOf + "s.";
            displayFinish = "Pair of " + setOf + "s. Win $50.00 dollars.";
        }
        if (!pair && !twoPair && !threeKind && !fullHouse && !fourKind
                && !straight && !flush && !straightFlush && !RoyalFlush
                && !royalStraight) {
            nothing = true;
            displayDeal = "You have nothing.";
            displayFinish = "Nothing. Lose 20.00 dollars.";
        }
        this.validate();

    }

    public int getFaceValue2(poker.Card card) {
        String s = card.getFace();
        byte byte0 = 0;
        if (s.equals(faces[0])) {
            byte0 = 2;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[1])) {
            byte0 = 3;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[2])) {
            byte0 = 4;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[3])) {
            byte0 = 5;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[4])) {
            byte0 = 6;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[5])) {
            byte0 = 7;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[6])) {
            byte0 = 8;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[7])) {
            byte0 = 9;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[8])) {
            byte0 = 10;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[9])) {
            byte0 = 11;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[10])) {
            byte0 = 12;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[11])) {
            byte0 = 13;
        }
        if (s.equals(faces[12])) {
            byte0 = 14;
        }
        return byte0;
    }

    public boolean sort2(poker.Card acard[]) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int ai[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ai[i] = getFaceValue2(acard[i]);
        }

        for (int k = 1; k < ai.length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < ai.length - 1; l++) {
                if (ai[l] > ai[l + 1]) {
                    int j = ai[l];
                    ai[l] = ai[l + 1];
                    ai[l + 1] = j;
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ai.length - 1; i1++) {
            if (ai[0] + 1 == ai[1] && ai[1] + 1 == ai[2] && ai[2] + 1
                    == ai[3] && ai[3] + 1 == ai[4]) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (flag) {
            System.out.print(hand[0] + " " + hand[1] + " " + hand[2] + " "
                    + hand[3] + " " + hand[4]);
        }
        System.out.print(ai[0] + " " + ai[1] + " " + ai[2] + " " + ai[3]
                + " " + ai[4]);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case its running fine, but this is not proper way of doing

Comment: must be slowness of your machine. Can you try on another machine if possible?

Comment: What is this `repaint()` request for ? Had you heard of [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) - Quote from Java Doc **"Swing components should be created, queried, and manipulated on the event-dispatching thread, but browsers don't invoke applet "milestone" methods from that thread. For this reason, the milestone methods — init, start, stop, and destroy — should use the SwingUtilities method invokeAndWait (or, if appropriate, invokeLater) so that code that refers to the Swing components is executed on the event-dispatching thread."**

Comment: Being your first question I had upvoted it, though Please do find time to read wonderful articles, [PERFECT QUESTION](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by @JonSkeet and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) by AndrewThompson , before you post your next question in any forum. Please do learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and stick to them :-)

Comment: i will read the article thanks for the suggestion. also i tried running the code in several machines and i always get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took sometime to modify the code of yours and I removed the paint() method and its working, now the screen display's without any freezing and all the components are displayed. Here's one important information for you which i found regarding paint() method when you extend JApplet.

Note: Move the logic which you had in your paint() method according to your design.

> However, JApplets have a lot of extra structure that plain Applets
>   don't have. Because of this structure, the painting of a JApplet is a
>   more complex affair and is handled by the system. So, when you make a
>   subclass of JApplet you should not write a paint() method for it. As
>   we will see, if you want to draw on a JApplet, you should add a
>   component to the  applet to be used for that purpose. On the other
>   hand, you can and generally should write an init() method for a
>   subclass of JApplet.

Below is the modified code, Hope it helps!!!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Poker extends JApplet implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {

    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    JList jList = new JList(listModel);
    JButton dealButton = new JButton("Deal card");
    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");  
    JButton finishButton = new JButton("finish");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    private Poker.Card deck[];
    private int currentCard;
    private int money;
    String faces[] = {
            "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", 
            "Ten", "Jack", 
            "Queen", "King", "Ace"
    };
    String suits[] = {
            "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"
    };
    private boolean card1State;
    private boolean card2State;
    private boolean card3State;
    private boolean card4State;
    private boolean card5State;
    private  Poker.Card hand[];
    private boolean pressed;
    private boolean nothing;
    private boolean pair;
    private boolean twoPair;
    private boolean threeKind;
    private boolean fourKind;
    private boolean fullHouse;
    private boolean flush;
    private boolean straight;
    private boolean royalStraight;
    private boolean straightFlush;
    private boolean RoyalFlush;
    private final int ROYALFLUSH = 8;
    private int value;
    private boolean firstDeal;

    @Override
    public void init(){

        this.setSize(500, 500);

        jList.addListSelectionListener(this);
        jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        hand = new Poker.Card[5];
        deck = new Poker.Card[52];
        currentCard = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
            deck[i] = new Poker.Card(faces[i % 13], suits[i / 13]);

        listModel.setSize(5);

        dealButton.addActionListener(this);
        finishButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);

        finishButton.setEnabled(false);

        // c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(dealButton);         
        panel.add(finishButton); 
        panel.add(quitButton); 

        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);         

        jPanel.add(jList);
        add(jPanel,  BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setVisible(true);

    }


    class Card 
    {
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return face + " of " + suit + "\n";
        }

        public String getFace()
        {
            return face;
        }

        public String getSuit()
        {
            return suit;
        }

        private String face;
        private String suit;

        public Card(String s, String s1)
        {
            face = s;
            suit = s1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        JList source = (JList) event.getSource();
        java.util.List values = source.getSelectedValuesList();
        listModel.removeElement(values);
        changeCards();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Poker.Card card = null;
        int i = 5;
        if(event.getSource() == dealButton){
            pressed = true;
            dealButton.setEnabled(false);
            finishButton.setEnabled(true);

            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                card = dealCard();
                hand[j] = card;
                listModel.setElementAt(hand[j], j);
            }
            if(money < -1000){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GAME OVER. ");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }else if( event.getSource() == finishButton){

            // still needs implementation

        } else if (event.getSource() == quitButton) {

            pressed = true;

            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Are you sure you want to exit?", "User Confirmation",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                dealButton.setEnabled(false);
                finishButton.setEnabled(false);
                quitButton.setEnabled(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.validate();
    }

    public void giveMoney() {
        if (nothing)
        {   money -= 20;
        }
        if (pair) {
            money += 50;
        }
        if (twoPair) {
            money += 100;
        }
        if (threeKind) {
            money += 150;
        }
        if (straight) {
            money += 200;
        }
        if (royalStraight)
        {
            money += 200;
        }
        if (flush) {
            money += 250;
        }
        if (fullHouse) {
            money += 300;
        }
        if (fourKind)
        {
            money += 400;
        }
        if (straightFlush) {
            money += 500;
        }
        if (RoyalFlush) {
            money += 1000;
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            int j = (int) (Math.random() * 52D);
            Poker.Card card = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = card;
        }
        dealButton.setEnabled(true);
        this.validate();
    }

    public Poker.Card dealCard() {

        if (++currentCard < deck.length) {
            return deck[currentCard];
        } else {
            dealButton.setEnabled(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

//  public void paint(Graphics g){
//
//      this.setBackground(Color.gray);
//      Font font = new Font("Italic", 3, 14);
//      g.setFont(font);        
//      if(pressed)
//      {          
//          Font font1 = new Font("Card", 1, 24);
//          g.setFont(font1);   
//
//          if(nothing)
//              g.drawString("You got nothing!! You lose $20 ", 50, 125);
//          if(pair)
//              g.drawString("A pair!! Win $50 ", 50, 125);
//          if(twoPair)
//              g.drawString("Two pair!! win $100 ", 50, 125);   
//          if(threeKind)
//              g.drawString("Three of a Kind!! Win $150 ", 50, 125);
//          if(straight)
//              g.drawString("A Straight!! Win $200 ", 50, 125);
//          if (royalStraight)
//              g.drawString("A Royal Straight!! Win $200 ", 50, 125);                
//          if(flush)
//              g.drawString("A Flush!! Win $250 ", 50, 125);
//          if(fullHouse)
//              g.drawString("A Full House!! Win $300 ", 50, 125);            
//          if(straightFlush)
//              g.drawString("A Straight Flush!! Win $500 ", 50, 125);
//          if(RoyalFlush)
//              g.drawString("A Royal Flush!! Win $100 ", 50, 125);            
//      }
//      
//      this.setVisible(true);
//  }

    public void changeCards(){

        System.out.println("change cards");

        firstDeal = true;
        Object obj = null;
        if(!card1State)
        {
            Poker.Card card = dealCard();
            hand[0] = card;
        }
        if(!card2State)
        {
            Poker.Card card6 = dealCard();
            hand[1] = card6;
        }
        if(!card3State)
        {
            Poker.Card card7 = dealCard();
            hand[2] = card7;
        }
        if(!card4State)
        {
            Poker.Card card8 = dealCard();
            hand[3] = card8;
        }
        if(!card5State)
        {
            Poker.Card card9 = dealCard();
            hand[4] = card9;

        }
    }

    public void evaluate() {

        int i = 0;
        if(hand[0].getSuit().equals(hand[1].getSuit()) && 
                hand[1].getSuit().equals(hand[2].getSuit()) && 
                hand[2].getSuit().equals(hand[3].getSuit()) && 
                hand[3].getSuit().equals(hand[4].getSuit()))
        {
            flush = true;
            if (flush == true)
                System.out.println("you got a a flush");
        }
        if(sort2(hand)){
            straight = true;
            if (straight = true)
                System.out.println("you got a a straight");
        }

        if(straight && flush)
        {
            straightFlush = true;
            straight = false;
            flush = false;
            System.out.println("you got a straight flush");
        }
        if(straightFlush)
        {
            for(int j = 9; j < 13; j++)
                if(hand[i].getFace().equals(faces[j]) && 
                        hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(faces[j + 1]) && 
                        hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(faces[j + 2]) && 
                        hand[i + 3].getFace().equals(faces[j + 3]) && 
                        hand[i + 4].getFace().equals(faces[j + 4]))
                {
                    straightFlush = false;
                    RoyalFlush = true;
                }

        }
        if(hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()))
            fourKind = true;
        else
            if(hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                    hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                    hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                    hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                    hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                    hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                    hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                    hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                    hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) || 
                    hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                    hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                    hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                    hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && !fullHouse)
            {
                System.out.println("2 pair=true;");
                twoPair = true;
            } else
                if(hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                        hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                        hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                        hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                        hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) || 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                        hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                        hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                        hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) || 
                        hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                        hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                        hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) && !straightFlush){        
                    fullHouse = true;

                }
        if((hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) && 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) && 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) || 
                hand[0].getFace().equals(hand[1].getFace()) &&
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) && 
                hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace()) &&
                hand[3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace()) || 
                hand[1].getFace().equals(hand[2].getFace()) &&
                hand[2].getFace().equals(hand[3].getFace())) && 
                !twoPair && !fullHouse && !fourKind){
            threeKind = true;


        }
        else
            if((hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 1].getFace()) || 
                    hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 2].getFace()) ||
                    hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace()) ||
                    hand[i].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace()) ||
                    hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 2].getFace()) ||
                    hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace()) || 
                    hand[i + 1].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace()) || 
                    hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(hand[i + 3].getFace()) || 
                    hand[i + 2].getFace().equals(hand[i + 4].getFace()) ||
                    hand[i + 3].getFace().equals(hand[4].getFace())) && 
                    !twoPair && !threeKind && !fullHouse){
                pair = true;

            }

            else
            {   nothing = true;
            System.out.println("you got nothing");
            }
        this.validate();
        // giveMoney();
    }

    public int getFaceValue2( Poker.Card card) {
        String s = card.getFace();
        byte byte0 = 0;
        if(s.equals(faces[0]))
            byte0 = 2;
        if(s.equals(faces[1]))
            byte0 = 3;
        if(s.equals(faces[2]))
            byte0 = 4;
        if(s.equals(faces[3]))
            byte0 = 5;
        if(s.equals(faces[4]))
            byte0 = 6;
        if(s.equals(faces[5]))
            byte0 = 7;
        if(s.equals(faces[6]))
            byte0 = 8;
        if(s.equals(faces[7]))
            byte0 = 9;
        if(s.equals(faces[8]))
            byte0 = 10;
        if(s.equals(faces[9]))
            byte0 = 11;
        if(s.equals(faces[10]))
            byte0 = 12;
        if(s.equals(faces[11]))
            byte0 = 13;
        if(s.equals(faces[12]))
            byte0 = 14;
        return byte0;
    }

    public boolean sort2( Poker.Card acard[]){
        boolean flag = false;
        int ai[] = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            ai[i] = getFaceValue2(acard[i]);

        for(int k = 1; k < ai.length; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < ai.length - 1; l++)
                if(ai[l] > ai[l + 1])
                {
                    int j = ai[l];
                    ai[l] = ai[l + 1];
                    ai[l + 1] = j;
                }

        }

        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < ai.length - 1; i1++)
            if(ai[0] + 1 == ai[1] && ai[1] + 1 == ai[2] && ai[2] + 1 == 
            ai[3] && ai[3] + 1 == ai[4])
                flag = true;
            else
                flag = false;

        if(flag)
            System.out.print(hand[0] + " " + hand[1] + " " + hand[2] + " " + 
                    hand[3] + " " + hand[4]);
        System.out.print(ai[0] + " " + ai[1] + " " + ai[2] + " " + ai[3] +
                " " + ai[4]);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code above to include the remaining code again thanks for the help.

Comment: Many Thanks for taking the time to review my code. I should be able to finish now.

Comment: If my suggestion and modified code has lead you to solve your problem you can select my answer as the solution.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance but how would i select your answer as the solution?

Comment: There should be a tick mark at the beginning of every solution posted, so if you click it, it would turn green :)

Comment: cool Thanks. Hey since iam writing to you let me ask you something. we managed to solve the issue with the buttons by removing the paint method right? However i need to paint two strings in the applet one when the user hits the deal button i must print if they have anything (pair,full house, etc) and another when they hit the finish button telling them how much they won. I tried doing that by re-enabling the paint method but then the issue with the buttons come back do you have any suggestions on how to approach this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this, You could create a label using
JLabel label = new JLabel();

and when the deal or finish button is clicked,
set the text of the JLabel something like this, or change
it based on your functionality under actionPerformed() method

label.setText("Display or do the similar thing !!!!");

dont forget to add the label in the panel like below in the init() method

panel.add(label); Hope its clear!!!

Comment: Hello Like to code sorry to bother but can i ask you yet another question? I have basically finished the code and as i was testing i found a but and it is driving me nuts. here is the issue when i press the deal button i get 5 cards i then evaluate the hand fine so far. If i do not make any changes and just hit finish it is fine no problems. however if i make a selection and get new cards when i reevaluate the hand the first list is evaluated it looks like the jlist is not being updated. It is strange because on screen i see the updated list i tried repaint() revalidate() no success code above

Comment: If I understand correctly, Why dont you try printing your cards that is added in list like below  System.out.println(card.getFace()); so you'll know whether it is adding it. I tested it, it seems when you make a selection and click the deal button a new set of cards is populated. I did this   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                card = dealCard();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(card.getFace());
                hand[j] = card;
                listModel.setElementAt(hand[j], j);
            }

Comment: Hello, I am doing a System.out, when i hit deal i get 5 cards and it shows me the cards the same five cards are displayed on the GUI. but when i select a card and hit finish the selected card is removed and a new card is added to the list, the GUI displays the changes, but  the system.out do not it shows me the initial 5 cards without any changes and when i reevaluate it seems that i reevaluate the initial five cards.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I was making the change the List but the change was not being made on the array that containing the elements of the list. all it needed was a single line of code and problem fixed. Thanks for all the help and i appreciate the time you toke  to help me.

Comment: Glad that your issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

When i run this applet using eclipse, it runs fine and i can see 2 buttons. Have you tried validating the applet after everything is ready?

```
this.validate();
this.repaint();
```

from Container.class:

> The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.